# Entity Framework Core Put request only partially updating will not update files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Issue: Edit data partially updating will not update the files part of the edit form.

I am using ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core 5 with a vue js front end. I do get all the data from the front end including the files but when it hits the save method it only saves the basic data and not the files.

this is my put request

```
    [HttpPut("{key:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutAsset(int key,[FromForm] AssetPutDto assetPutDto)
    {
        IList<AssetFile> assetFiles = new List<AssetFile>();
        if (assetPutDto.Files == null)
            {
                assetFiles = null;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var file in assetPutDto.Files)
                {
                    if (file.Length <= 0) continue;
                    await using var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();

                    var thisFile = new AssetFile()
                    {
                        File = fileBytes,
                        Name = file.FileName,
                        MimeType = file.ContentType
                    };
                    assetFiles.Add(thisFile);
                }
            }

            assetPutDto.AssetFiles = assetFiles;
            var asset = _mapper.Map<Asset>(assetPutDto);
            asset.Id = key;
            
            _context.Entry(asset).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException dce)
            {
                if (!AssetExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dce.ToString());
                }
            }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

and this is my AssetPutDTO

```
    public class AssetPutDto : AssetDto
    {
            /// <summary>
           /// Sets the files to Iformfile format to process it to the database
          /// </summary>
          public IList<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
          // TODO: RetireDate
         // Gets and sets the AssetFiles property
         public IList<AssetFile> AssetFiles { get; set; }
    }
```

The result I am looking for is that I want to update the data including the files. I am just stumped at this point in why it is not working as it should.

any help in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: You sure, your _mapper object is mapping your `assetPutDto.AssetFiles`? set a break point after the _mapper.Map method invokation and be sure that your assetFiles are being mapped correclty. Also if AssetFiles data are being saved in another table, i'm unsure if ef will understand and replace previously saved joined-table data

Comment: @Patrick  Took a look at the mapper and it seems to be mapping the files I mean i get the asset all the way to the _context.Entry point but after that nothing. The asset files are indeed saved in their own table if ef core is not understanding that how to i get it to update that table aswell as the asset table ?

Comment: you could load the asset entity with its navigation property either by eager or lazyloading, removing then manually and inserting the new assetFiles

Comment: could you help out with an example on how I can do that I am still new to ef core and still figuring it all out on what I need to do ... thanks

Comment: I will provide an answer, am just testing things out to make sure I pass the correctly information and not only how you resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core works by representing your data in objects, but as your code show not always an object of the same type as the Code representation of your table record will be know to entity, so in order to entity to acknowledge the object as a reference to your record the key must be correclty set and you "forcefully" tells entity that this object has been changed and it must now update it accordling through `_context.Entry(asset).State = EntityState.Modified;` but as you do this entity will only aknowledge and track the asset object and all its relationships will be ignored.

## TL;DR

1. make EF load the relationship before making changes to them by first
   attaching the object to the context using `_context.Attach(asset);`
2. loading previous relationship from database with `await _context.Entry(asset).Collection(d => d.Files).LoadAsync();`
3. making your changes to the relationship (either using your automapper or manually saving the previous collection beforehand and resetting here
4. update using `await _context.SaveChangedAsync()`

## Detailed

> in your case EF does not update its relationships because they aren't being **tracked**

in this [repository](https://github.com/patrickhacens/stackoverflow_ef_update/tree/master) I made some tests to be really sure that is what's hapenning and indeed it is.

> Run migrations and then `InitialSeed()` method first to seed the data that we will be testing

if you run `CaseReproduction()` it will reproduce what is happening in your code and will supply the console with usefull logs

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Assets] SET [Name] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

in this log we can see that the properties of the `asset` are being changed but there is nothing about the `assetfiles`

but if we make entity recognize and load its relationship before we make changes (by running `CaseCorrection()` method) we see that entity loads and acknowledges the `asset` relationship to `assetfiles` and updates them accordingly with the following log:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [AssetFiles]
WHERE [Id] = @p0;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [AssetFiles]
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [AssetFiles]
WHERE [Id] = @p2;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [AssetFiles]
WHERE [Id] = @p3;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [AssetFiles]
WHERE [Id] = @p4;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

INSERT INTO [AssetFiles] ([Id], [AssetId], [Name])
VALUES (@p5, @p6, @p7),
(@p8, @p9, @p10);
UPDATE [Assets] SET [Name] = @p11
WHERE [Id] = @p12;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

PS: you could also eager load your entity with all its relationship instead of creating a new object and attaching it to your database with `_context.Assets.Include(asset => asset.AssetFiles).FirstOrDefault(d=> d.Id == key);` and then change this object with or without your automapper

Comment: Thank you for your help on this,